# How to select from a table with criteria needing to match a temporary table?

Tags: mysql, select, temp-tables

I have two tables. One contains articles, the other one price quotations. I'm trying to select `[EAN]` from the articles table and `price` from the quotation table if dimensions in both tables are matching.

Here is the example I'm playing around with:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS haha;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE haha (
    tmp_kto VARCHAR(7) DEFAULT ''
    , tmp_kz VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ''
    , tmp_preisliste VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT ''
    , tmp_eg VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ''
    , tmp_length VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ''
    , tmp_width VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ''
    , tmp_price DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00
    ) ENGINE=MEMORY;

INSERT INTO haha (
    tmp_kz, tmp_kto, tmp_preisliste, tmp_eg, tmp_length, tmp_width, tmp_price
    ) VALUES (
    "000","4316134","I","520","150","200","14.95"
    );
INSERT INTO haha (
    tmp_kz, tmp_kto, tmp_preisliste, tmp_eg, tmp_length, tmp_width, tmp_price
    ) VALUES (
    "001","112233","L","520","150","200","17.95"
    );
```

Matching criteria should be `[EG]`and `[size]`. For `size` I need to substring the relevant size out of the field (no other way, I think - format is e.g. 050x250cm).

```
SELECT ean, preis 
    FROM (
    SELECT  a.ean AS ean
           , h.tmp_price AS preis
    FROM articles AS a
    LEFT JOIN haha AS h
        ON h.tmp_eg = a.eg
        AND h.tmp_kz = "000"
        AND h.tmp_kto = "0000000"
        AND h.tmp_preisliste = "I"
        AND h.tmp_length = SUBSTRING(a.size,1,3)
        AND h.tmp_width = SUBSTRING(a.size,4,3)
) AS temp;
```

Which does not work.

**Question:**
What do I need to change to make it work?

**EDIT**
2nd table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ean` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `size` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `eg` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO articles (
    ean, size, eg
    ) VALUES (
    "1111111111111","150x200cm","520"
    );

INSERT INTO articles (
    ean, size, eg
    ) VALUES (
    "2222222222222","150x220cm","520"
    );
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: alas, a comma was missing... let's see if that helps

Comment: where is second tAble ?

Comment: I post a few records. 1min-

Comment: Got it. Posting below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use simply like that ?

```
SELECT a.ean, h.tmp_price AS preis 
FROM articles AS a
LEFT JOIN haha AS h
    ON h.tmp_eg = a.eg
WHERE h.tmp_kz = "000"
    AND h.tmp_kto = "0000000"
    AND h.tmp_preisliste = "I"
    AND h.tmp_length = SUBSTRING(a.size,1,3)
    AND h.tmp_width = SUBSTRING(a.size,4,3)
```

Comment: :-D Just the same I came up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easier than thought:

```
    SELECT a.ean AS ean,
           h.tmp_price AS preis
    FROM articles AS a
    LEFT JOIN haha AS h
    ON h.tmp_eg = a.eg

    WHERE a.iln = "some_id"
    AND h.tmp_kz = "000"
    AND h.tmp_kto = "0000000"
    AND h.tmp_preisliste = "I"
    AND h.tmp_length = SUBSTRING(a.groesse,1,3)
    AND h.tmp_width = SUBSTRING(a.groesse,5,3)
```